# react-native-video this.player.presentFullscreenPlayer() auto landscape

Tags: reactjs, react-native

By using `react-native-video` , in iOS how can call `this.player.presentFullscreenPlayer()` and directly rotate to landscape . I have try to use `react-native-orientation` to `Orientation.lockToLandscape();` together when call `this.player.presentFullscreenPlayer()` , seem not work. There is a function call `setFullscreen` in `RTCVideo.m` , does anyone know how to modified so that when trigger `this.player.presentFullscreenPlayer()` it start from landscape , Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar with `react-native-orientation` and it works for me. You can something of this sort.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Orientation from "react-native-orientation";
import VideoPlayer from "react-native-video-controls";


const propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  pageUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};


class VideoDetail extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    Orientation.lockToPortrait();
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <VideoPlayer
        disableFullscreen
        disableVolume
        repeat
        goBack={this.goBack}
        ignoreSilentSwitch={"ignore"}
        source={{
          uri: this.props.pageUrl,
          type: "mp4"
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

VideoDetail.propTypes = propTypes;

export default VideoDetail;
```

This will work with rotation nicely. But there is small glitch in package, it takes default orientations as all orientations enabled, so you might want to change that else your entire app will be landscape enabled.

```
static UIInterfaceOrientationMask _orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
+ (void)setOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)orientation {
  _orientation = orientation;
}
+ (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)getOrientation {
  return _orientation;
}
```

[source](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation/blob/99f8452c5debc0b27d50c0154d05403fe9567a29/iOS/RCTOrientation/Orientation.m#L16)

Comment: Where I need to change it to work properly, currently when i rotate my screen, it is restarting the app in landscape mode

Comment: Looks like I missed to add the source link, updated the answer, please check.